# bluebird How to pass argument to promise chain?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

```
UserService.register = function(email, password, nickname, birth, sex){

    promise.resolve(email).then(getUser).then(checkUserRepeat);

    function getUser(email){
        return userModel.findUser(email);
    }

    function checkUserRepeat(user){
        if(user == null)
             return userModel.insertUser() =>HERE I WANT ARGUMENT email,password, nickname, birth, sex
            .then(insertResult);
        else
            return codeConfig.REGISTER_EMAIL_REPEAT;
    }

    function insertResult(result){
        if (result != null)
            return codeConfig.REGISTER_SUCCESS;
        else
            return codeConfig.REGISTER_SQL_ERROR;
    }
}
```

"userModel.insertUser" must pass argument email,password, nickname, birth, sex,how to do it?

Comment: Why can't you pass it to `userModel.insertUser()`? I assume the method already returns a promise.

Comment: like this? `userModel.insertUser ({ email:email, password:password, nickname:nickname, birth:birth, sex:sex });`

Comment: yes why you cannot do that ?

Comment: it's my fault. thanks。I forgot the closure rule。@Bek,  @Abu Ashraf Masnun